# how will the minimal triangulation of a torus look like?

Tags: homological-algebra

how how will the minimal triangulation of a torus look like?

Answer (score 11):

Let $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/3}$. Let $L$ be the planar lattice generated by $1$ and $\omega$. Let $M$ be the sublattice generated by $2-\omega$ and $\omega (2 - \omega)$. Tile $\mathbb{R}^2$ by equilateral triangles with vertices at $L$, and quotient by $M$. This is a triangulation of the torus with $7$ vertices (exercise!). It is minimal because any triangulation of the torus must have a vertex of degree $6$, so you can't get use fewer vertices.

Comment: As a bonus this shows the embedding of $K_7$ in the torus, and the dual graph is the strongly regular Heawood graph (= incidence graph of the Fano plane) and tiles the torus with $7$ pairwise adjacent hexagons. 

Comment: [Correction: the Heawood graph isn't quite strongly regular, but it *is* vertex- and edge-transitive.]

Comment: Moreover, Dewdney proved in "Wagner’s theorem for torus graphs" Discrete Math. 4 (1973), 139–149, that every triangulation of the torus can be transformed to this one by a sequence of flips and edge contractions.

Comment: Moreover, this $7$-vertex triangulation can be realized as an embedded simplicial complex in $3$-space, so you can actually see it.  (I made one out of construction paper during an idle undergraduate afternoon.)  For more information about this, see, for example, http://www.eg-models.de/models/Classical_Models/2001.02.069/_preview.html . 

Comment: Why can't I use fewer vertices? Does the definition of "triangulation" preclude an edge that joins a vertex to itself?

Comment: I was taking the definition of a triangulation to ban self-edges, and ban having two edges between the same pair of vertices. If you allow self-edges, you only need one vertex. (Quotient $L$ by itself.) If you ban self edges but allow multiple edges, You can get by with $3$: (Quotient $L$ by the span of $1-\omega$ and $\omega-\omega^2$; you can't use less because every triangle must have three distinct vertices.)